# How to dynamically create component inside child component in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement something like light version of `mat-table` form Angular Material. And i can't create component inside child component. Here is some code and link to stackblitz at the end.

In some `*.html` file:

```
<table uiTable></table>
```

Base UiTable component:

```
// ui-table.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'table[uiTable]',
  template: `
    <thead uiTableHead></thead>
  `,
})
export class UiTableComponent implements AfterContentInit {

  @ViewChild(UiTableHeadDirective, {static: true}) 
  private tableHead: UiTableHeadDirective;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ) {}

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    const rowFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(UiTableRowComponent);

    this.tableHead.viewContainer.clear();
    this.tableHead.viewContainer.createComponent(rowFactory);
  }

}
```

`ui-table-head.directive` and `ui-table-row.component` - just empty angular directive and component with injected `ViewContainerRef`.

I expect that after `ngAfterContentInit` is done I will get something like

```
<table uiTable>
    <thead uiTableHead>
        <tr uiTableRow></tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

But instead of it i get

```
<table uiTable>
    <thead uiTableHead></thead>
    <tr uiTableRow></tr>
    <!--container-->
    <!--container-->
</table>
```

Why? I call `createComponent` method from `tableHead.viewContainer`, but new component creates inside `uiTable`.
What's wrong?

Stackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ui-table

Comment: It was historically decided that a dynamically creating component is placed next to the anchor. Anchor in your case is `thead`

Comment: @yurzui oh, ok( is there some way to create a component inside anchor? put anchor inside thead, wait for content init and call `createComponent` from it? Or maybe something more easy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can forward your dynamically created component to children by using the following snippet:

```
const componentRef = this.tableHead.viewContainer.createComponent(rowFactory);
this.tableHead.viewContainer.element.nativeElement
                .appendChild(componentRef.location.nativeElement);
```

[**Forked Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ui-table-x421u3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fui-table%2Fui-table.component.ts)